# php library iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, static-libraries

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a PHP library that I could compile into my app for the iPhone? Basically I'm wanting to allow the phone to display pages stored locally that have PHP in them and display them in a UIWebView.

Comment: So you're talking about a PHP server for your IPhone? Unlikely.

Comment: While a PHP server would is not allowed according to Apple's rules something that precompiles the php into an Iphone binary could theoretically exist (like Adobe's Flash compiling thing). However it is very unlikely...

Comment: Yes basically I wanted a local web server able to serve PHP, I just don't need it to serve it to other devices. But I forgot about Apple's no interpreter rules… :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple are extremely strict about not allowing 3rd-party code execution engines in apps, which would prohibit running a PHP interpreter.

If PHP is a true requirement, you'll have to host it on an external server and access the pages remotely.

Consider Javascript as an alternative language if you need to stay local, it's really the only way to execute run-time-generated code on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

In order for that to work you would need:

- A PHP compatible webserver running on your iPhone
- Some sort of a PHP interpreter (not that there are so many different types of them out there) running on it too

I don't think this is/will be possible when thinking of Apple's strictness regarding 3rd party software and the low chances of someone even planning a port of PHP for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this PHP library?  http://php.net/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

Running your debugged PHP code in an iOS app makes a lot of sense to me. Getting a PHP library in an iOS app and approved by Apple isn't easy, but it's been done. See: [Running PHP on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213804/running-php-on-ios/17883443) for details.